# How to count how many arrays occured in np arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Suppose I have:

```
x = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 3]]
```

and I want to have an output something like this:

```
count = [0, 1] = 2, [0, 2] = 2, [0, 3] = 1
```

How can I count how many arrays occurred?

Comment: Where is the numpy?

Comment: What attempt or research have you done so far?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class like:

#### Code:

```
Counter(tuple(i) for i in x)
```

Note that since a `Counter` is a `dict`, the keys need to be hashable.  This is why the `tuple(i) for i in x` is needed, since that will convert the lists in `x` to tuples so that they can be used as keys for the `Counter`.

#### Test Code:

```
x = [[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 3]]

from collections import Counter
print(Counter(tuple(i) for i in x))
```

#### Results:

```
Counter({(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 2, (0, 3): 1})
```

Comment: You may want to mention why `Counter` being a `dict` means you can't just do `Counter(x)`. +1 regardless.

Comment: this is great! but how can i select to print only where count > c? so when i set c = 1, (0, 3):1 is not printed

Comment: `Counter(i for i in counts if i[1] > c)` where `counts = Counter(tuple(i) for i in x)`

Answer (score 2):

In `numpy` you can use `np.unique`, e.g.:

```
In []:
np.unique(x, axis=0, return_counts=True)

Out[]:
(array([[0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3]]), array([2, 2, 1]))
```

If you want to collapse them then you can use `zip()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
list(zip(*np.unique(x, axis=0, return_counts=True)))

Out[]:
[(array([0, 1]), 2), (array([0, 2]), 2), (array([0, 3]), 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for pure numpy solution:

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: x = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 3]])

In [14]: np.unique(x, axis=0, return_counts=True)
Out[14]: 
(array([[0, 1],
        [0, 2],
        [0, 3]]), array([2, 2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

THe following code will solve it

```
print({str(i):x.count(i) for i in x})
```

Comment: I ran this and got `[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]` in both python 2.7 and python 3.5.

Comment: that gives the count for each of the element

Comment: But that's not what OP wants. OP was looking for `count = [0, 1] = 2, [0, 2] = 2, [0, 3] = 1` or something similar.

Comment: Now it outputs `[([0, 1], 2), ([0, 1], 2), ([0, 2], 2), ([0, 2], 2), ([0, 3], 1)]`. Still not really what OP asked for.

Comment: Why `str(i)`? Why not just `i`?

Comment: list is not a hashable type. so, it can't be a key in a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

#### **1. Using** `.count`:

---

```
result = set((tuple(item), x.count(item)) for item in x)
print(result)
```

**Result**:

```
{((0, 1), 2), ((0, 2), 2), ((0, 3), 1)}
```

---

#### **2. Using** `defaultdict`:

---

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for item in x:
    result[tuple(item)] += 1
    
print(dict(result))
```

**Result**:

```
{(0, 1): 2, (0, 3): 1, (0, 2): 2}
```

---

#### **3. Using** `Counter`:

---

```
from collections import Counter

result = list(Counter(map(tuple, x)).items())
print(result)
```

**Result**:

```
[((0, 1), 2), ((0, 3), 1), ((0, 2), 2)]
```